# Are Istanbul Airport smoking lounges open during the COVID restrictions?

Tags: covid-19, event-based-effects, ist

Are the smoking lounges in the international departures airside of Istanbul airport operational during this time?

Are any restaurants selling alcoholic beverages as of right now in October 2020?

Comment: No room for niceties in COVID I guess :) referring to removal of extra words such as hello from the original post :)

Comment: It's a fairly general norm on Stack Exchange that salutations, "thanks", etc. are noise that should be removed ... https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/480/thanks-and-politeness-forms/481#481 ... this is meant to be efficient, not non-welcoming ... https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: Ben, I realize the noise and efficiency equation. That's why my comment had 2 smiley faces :). Thank you for sharing those links.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.